# Pivot in Mysql(phpmyadmin) on dates without sum or MAX

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I want to show my data in this format, [data view client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcIyF.png),
And my Database structure is in this format, [Sql View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCyVE.png)

---

EDITED
I want to show my data in this format,

---

```
Name (Father name)  Jan (PKR)   Feb (PKR)   Mar (PKR)   Apr (PKR)
castiel(siddiqui)   20110                                           
Gull(yasal)         20010
```

---

And my DB structure is

```
c_id    name   salary       ds_id   amount      date_time
3       abc     20000       1       20010       2023-01-07 
4       abc     20000       2       20010       2023-01-07 
5       abc     20000       3       20010       2023-01-07 
6       abc     20000       4       20010       2023-01-07
6       abc     20000       5       20011       2023-02-07
```

---

I created this sql query without join to just check if I can, but no joy

```
SELECT courier.name
,MAX(IF(DATE_FORMAT(dis_salary.date_time,'%Y-m')='2023', dis_salary.amount,NULL)) as salary
FROM dis_salary
JOIN courier ON courier.c_id=dis_salary.courier_id
GROUP BY courier.c_id
```

I don't want to show max or sum, and all the dates are variable, so cant hardcode

I want to show each salary given to courier w.r.t month

Also the project is in PHP CodeIgniter, if that helps

output i want

---

| name | month1 | month2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 20010 | 20011 |

Comment: You should be selecting and grouping by courier and aggregating by month. Also please add sample data as text which we can use as opposed to images which we can't.

Comment: Please review now, edited

Comment: Since you have to group by to bring the different values into a single row per courier, you have to use an aggregate function. However, if a courier has only one salary per month, then max, min, avg, sum will all return the same amount. If a courier can have multiple salaries in a month that would give you a problem, but your question has not defined how to handle such situations, so we cannot give you a definite answer for that

Comment: Salaries are only given once per month, also the question is marked as duplicate so, let me check with the duplicated question and get back to you here

Comment: @shadow I've change the code, can you please guide me how to, i want data in months format and its only showing 1 salary of the year, I'll be setting only year dynamically to fetch all salaries per month in a year

Comment: You have put in one conditional check only, so you get one result. Your code does not follow the logic described in the accepted answer.